# How to do a weighted average in my pivot table that follows a filtering criteria?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have an idea how to create a simple weighted average, but what makes this application a bit confusing for me is because the weights are based on a ratio--where its denominator is a sum of all rows that contain the same name.

I think it has something to do with `calculated fields` or `DAX` but I have no experience on how to formulate it on Excel.

Please refer to image below:
[image]

Comment: can you explain the logic in words instead of a math formula with symbols that people may not know?

Comment: Thank you i'll add them in words also when I get to work. I placed the same exact formula in the rightmost column in excel formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to first add this table to the Power Pivot data model. I will call this table "Data".

Then, create a DAX measure:

```
Weighted Average = 
DIVIDE ( 
    SUMX ( Data, Data[Production Quantity] * Data[Average] ), 
    SUM ( Data[Production Quantity] ) 
    )
```

Create a pivot table with Name on the rows, drop the measure into it, and you will get this result:

[image]

(please note that your example shows incorrect calculations for Name D).